# Where to add Device tree Overlay in yocto

Tags: overlay, beagleboneblack, device-tree, yocto-recipe

In yocto i want to add one Device tree overlay for DHT11 Sensor. Previously there is no device tree overlay for DHT11 but it have the Device Driver.

I want to configure a GPIO pin for the DHT11 sensor but before that we have to add the overlay.

If we write the device tree overlay means at which path, i mean where we have to add in the meta_yocto_bsp or we have to add it. we have to add it in the Yocto and how to configure.

I have created a directory in meta_*yocto_*bsp  in that directory i have written the device tree file and extension is .dts and generated the .dtbo file.

I enable the device tree over lay menuconfig.

still i unable to find it in target.